# ScalaFX & CSS Files (Using Java 8)

Tags: java, scala, javafx, sbt, scalafx

I am using ScalaFX with Java 8 and I am running into difficulties getting ScalaFX to us a CSS file.

Everything I have read up to this point says to use something along these lines:

```
object testObj extends JFXApp {
  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene {
      stylesheets += this.getClass.getResource("/css/app.css").toExternalForm
      var nbutton = new Button("Submit")
      content_=(List(nbutton))
    }
  }
}
```

If I don't bother with trying to add a stylesheet, the app fires right up. However, if I do attempt to add the css file, this is what my console tells me:

```
[info] Running TestTool 
Exception in Application start method
Workaround until RT-13281 is implemented: keep toolkit alive
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestTool$$anon$3$$anon$4.<init>(Main.scala:20)
    at TestTool$$anon$3.<init>(Main.scala:19)
    at TestTool$.delayedEndpoint$TestTool$1(Main.scala:14)
    at TestTool$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:13)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$class.scalafx$application$JFXApp$class$$$anonfun$2(JFXApp.scala:250)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$class.scalafx$application$JFXApp$class$$$anonfun$2$adapted(JFXApp.scala:250)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$class.init(JFXApp.scala:250)
    at TestTool$.init(Main.scala:13)
    at scalafx.application.AppHelper.start(AppHelper.scala:32)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
```

And of course the application is not started.

Everything I have read up to this point makes it seem like it's an issue with Java 8. I am at a loss as to where to proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: It appears it can't find your css file.  Check that it can find it before performing the toExternalForm where the null is getting thrown.

Comment: I'm not a scala programmer (though I think I can read this code): most likely the path to the css file is wrong. It is going to look for app.css in a package called css, relative to the classpath at runtime. So you need to make sure 1. you have that structure, 2. the css file is getting deployed along with the class files generated, and (if you're bundling as a jar file) 3. the css is included in the jar.

Comment: @purringpigeon I added a since check if(this.getClass.getResource("app.css")!=null)println ("Found") else ("Not Found") and I received "Found" confirming that it is finding it.

Comment: You are looking for "app.css" but your code above says: this.getClass.getResource("/css/app.css").  I am not a scala programmer, but in Java I have found issues with the leading "/"

Comment: Sorry I've been typing and changing all kinds of stuff.
The file was in css/app.css and I got so desperate I literally placed the file in every folder just because..well why not. I still receive the error.